# Unwanted extra padding around custom View element

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout, padding

**!!!PROBLEM SOLVED!!!**

**The problem was overridden onLayout function after removing it from code everything works as expected!**

I created my own View object extending RelativeLayout, it displays but it applies some extra padding(image bellow) - The grey area is the size of custom element added to main XML Layout(Size as expected) and the green is the view inflated to the element which somehow takes extra padding in accordance with height of elements above(as you can see on image 2).

Why is this happening? I want the TextView(green part) to fill the full parent(grey part) also I noticed that it has proper size it just moved down out of the screen on bottom.

Can anybody help me please figure this one out?

[Image of screen 1](http://www.2i.cz/8a72c1eb38)

[Image of screen 2](http://www.2i.cz/76be0d27f4)

**logview.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stateLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/logBox"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/bt_status"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<com.canlab.carguard.view.LogView
    android:id="@+id/logBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/carLabel"
    android:background="@color/l_blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/driverLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Řidič:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/driverLabel"
    android:text="Auto:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

**LogView.class**

```
public class LogView extends RelativeLayout  {
private final static String TAG = "LogView";
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private final int maxLines = 100;
private boolean scroll = true;
private final TextView log;
private final ImageButton pauseButton;


private int i = 0;


public LogView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.logview, null)); 
    pauseButton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    log = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    initView(context);

    this.setScrollBarStyle(SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
}

public LogView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.logview, null)); 
    pauseButton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    log = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    initView(context);
}


public LogView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.logview,null));

    pauseButton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    log = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    initView(context);

}


private void initView(Context context){
    log.setTextSize(15);
    log.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    log.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    log.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i = 0 ; i < getChildCount() ; i++){
        getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a real stumper!

Comment: Problem solved!! After removing overridden onLayout everything works as expected now!

Comment: Wow, that was really weird.

Comment: Indeed, I usually find my way to solve problems but this was a nightmare! Still don't know why it resolved the problem though.